# bash: mysql query to curl, using read for variables

Tags: mysql, bash, curl, sed

I am stuck on this one and need some help. What I am trying to do is to run a mysql query, it will output some variables (multiple lines) which I use to generate a url that I call with curl. I am using read for lack of more knowledge. Also using sed to replace the spaces in the "spaces" with "%20"

My problem is that some of my mysql columns contain sentences and I only seem to grab the first word in the address1 and address2 column. The "comments" column pull through correctly though which is strange to me. Any help or pointers appreciated.

Table example:

```
+---------+------------+-----------+------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+----------+-----------+-----------------+--------------------------+
| lead_id | first_name | last_name | phone_code | phone_number | alt_phone | address1    | address2 | source_id | security_phrase | comments                 |
+---------+------------+-----------+------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+----------+-----------+-----------------+--------------------------+
|    1699 | import1    | yes       | 27         | 211100223    | 123456787 | branch name | 7777     | 96857447  | 8206115050500   | some comments here Danny |
|    1700 | import2    | yes       | 27         | 211100224    | 123456788 | branch name | 7777     | 96857447  | 8206115050500   | some comments here  |
+---------+------------+-----------+------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+----------+-----------+-----------------+--------------------------+
```

My script:

```
        while read -a lead_id first_name last_name phone_code phone_number alt_phone address1 address2 source_id security_phrase comments
do
        echo "echo lead_id if = "$lead_id""
                if [ "$lead_id" = "lead_id" ]
                then echo "skipping null string"
                else
                LINK="HTTPS://HIDDEN-LINK?campaign=SMS&telephony_incoming_id="$lead_id"&Firstname="$first_name"&Lastname="$last_name"&cellphone="$phone_number"&WorkPhone="$alt_phone"&branch_name="$address1"&branch_code="$address2"&Client_key="$source_id"&field_ID_Number="$security_phrase"&currentaction="$comments""

                echo $LINK

                LINK2=`echo "$LINK"|sed 's/ /%20/g'`

                echo $LINK2
                /usr/bin/curl "$LINK2"

                fi
        done < <(echo "SELECT lead_id, first_name, last_name, phone_code, phone_number, alt_phone, address1, address2, source_id, security_phrase, comments FROM table where list_id='$LISTID'" | /usr/bin/mysql -uroot -D database)
fi

echo "we are done here"

exit 0
```

Some output of Echo, see how it gets messed up from branch_name onward:

```
HTTPS://HIDDEN-LINK?campaign=SMS&telephony_incoming_id=1699&Firstname=import1&Lastname=yes&cellphone=211100223&WorkPhone=123456787&branch_name=branch&branch_code=name&Client_key=7777&field_ID_Number=96857447&currentaction=8206115050500 some comments here Danny
```

Thank you for helping. If I should use something other than read please point me in the right direction.

Comment: You've got all kinds of quoting issues; i would suggest running your script through http://www.shellcheck.net/ ...

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query